# JQuery encodeURIComponent page not found error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, url, encoding

I'm trying to encode my `uri` by using `encodeURIComponent` function. Here is my code.

```
//res[0].CLIENT_ID=10 and id=res[0].CLIENT_ID
var url = "new_quotation.php?clientid="+res[0].CLIENT_ID+"&quoteid="+id;
var encodedurl = encodeURIComponent(url);
$('#edit').attr("href", encodedurl);
```

It successfully encodes the `uri`, but when the page redirects it shows error as

> The requested URL /Quotation/new_quotation.php?clientid=10&quoteid=0000000014 was not found on this server.

I saw the `url`. It seems like

`http://localhost/Quotation/new_quotation.php%3Fclientid%3D10%26quoteid%3D0000000014`

So, the uri is encoded but why not the page is redirected? Do I need to use any other function to redirect? Or is there any error in my code?

Comment: There is no reason to encode the entire thing

Comment: @epascarello What you mean?

Comment: use `encodeURIComponent(res[0].CLIENT_ID)` and `encodeURIComponent(id)` instead of encoding the entire url

Answer (score 0):

You should only be encoding the values, not the entire url.

```
var url = "new_quotation.php?clientid="+encodeURIComponent(res[0].CLIENT_ID)+"&quoteid="+encodeURIComponent(id);
$('#edit').attr("href", url);
```

Since you are using jQuery, you can also use [`param()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/)

Comment: Because that is how it works...It does not figure out the url and encode only the portions. You need to do that.

Comment: If I use `encodeURIComponent(res[0].CLIENT_ID)` it doesn't encode anything

Comment: Is it a special character?

Comment: It shows url as `http://localhost/Quotation/new_quotation.php?clientid=10&quoteid=0000000014` which is the same as original

Comment: Which is 100% valid. Now enter in a space, &, ? or something else. It will encode it.  `console.log(encodeURIComponent("10%!"));`

Comment: From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent): "`Description:
encodeURIComponent escapes all characters except the following: alphabetic, decimal digits, - _ . ! ~ * ' ( )`"

Comment: There is no special characters like this, they contains only numbers

Comment: What is your point? It is working the way it should be working...You have a valid URL.

Comment: Yes, because there are no special characters. If you had a "special" character in `res[0].CLIENT_ID` it would encode it.

Answer (score 0):

Each and every parameter in the URL must be applied encodeURIComponent (if the parameter consists of special characters)

Example :

```
var enc =param1+'/'+encodeURIComponent(param2)+'/'+encodeURIComponent(param3);
```

param2, param3 - here are expected to have special chars